# Copy files to a destination folder only if the files already exist. but the source files have a different file extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename, file-copy

### Copy files to a destination folder only if the files already exist. but the source files have a different file extension.

i.e
I have a backup of some files with "**.desktop.in**" extension and I want to copy to destination where the files extensions are "**.desktop**" and only the files that already exist in the destination.

#### source folder contain:

- a.desktop.in
- b.desktop.in
- c.desktop.in

#### destination folder contain:

- a.desktop
- b.desktop

Want only to overwrite **a.desktop** and **b.desktop** files

Tried this:

```
for file in /destination/*.desktop;do cp /src/"${file##*/}".in "$file";done
```

But that doesn't look optimized for that task.

Do you know a better way to do that?

Comment: Do you have access to GNU tar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two ways:

```
for file in /src/*.desktop.in; do
  file=${file%.in}
  if test -e "/dest/$(basename ${file})"
    then cp "/src/${file}.in" "/dest/${file}"
  fi
done
```

rsync and --existing:

```
for file in /src/*.desktop.in; do 
  rsync --dry-run --existing --verbose "/src/${file}" "/dest/${file%.in}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in /destination/*.desktop; do echo cp "/src/${file##*/}.in" "$file"; done
```

If everything looks good, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically as good as it gets.

You can save a tiny bit of file name manipulation by changing to the directory where you're enumerating the files. It's a matter of readability, not performance.

```
set -e
cd /destination
for file in *.desktop; do
  cp "/src/$file.in" "$file"
done
```

Don't forget to check for failures.